# English equivalent of saying “Don’t get in between the nail and the flesh”?

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-requests, popular-refrains, proverb-requests

The saying “Don’t get in between the nail and the flesh” from my own language is typically addressed to someone who likes to provide unsolicited help by barging in on a heated conversation between two people; usually ending up making things worse by adding more oil to the fire.

I’m looking for an equivalent expression in English.

Comment: That's a **nasty** idiom; beautiful! What language is it, and how is it written?

Comment: In Italian it's *Tra moglie e marito non mettere il dito.* (don't meddle = *put a finger*  between a husband and wife)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not necessarily an argument between wife and husband - could be two relatives, two friends etc. and since it's a metaphor it can also refer to other than people; e.g two conflicting parties as someone's comment (deleted) hinted to.

Comment: That's why I didn't propose it as an answer :) I can't think of an idiom in Italian nor English that captures your native one quite so well. I'm stuck!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm glad to hear this -- at least you admit you can't find an equivalent idiom. I respect that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can consider the proverb ***"Don't go between the tree and the bark."*** (as common usages are listed already.)

It conveys the precise meaning you are looking for (analogy to *nail* and *flesh*) but it never gained a common usage; and might be mainly literary. [There are also other usages with the phrase "between the tree and the bark".]

> Meaning: Don't interfere when two people are having an argument.
>
> <sub>*[English proverbs](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/English_proverbs_%28alphabetically_by_proverb%29)* / *wikiquote.org*</sub>

It might be of European origin but it is mentioned in the novel *the Modern Griselda* by Maria Edgeworth (1804) which might be the first usage in English. [Maria Edgeworth is an Anglo-Irish writer].

[image]

But, an earlier usage is mentioned in *Le Médecin malgré lui* (a comedy by *Molière* first presented in 1666) where the character *Sganarelle* misquotes *Cicero*. (from the book *The Dramatic Works of Molière* by Molière)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something that carries the same violence as the original might be the idea of **getting in the crossfire**, i.e.

> Leave Bob and Alice alone! You don't want to get stuck in the crossfire, do you?

Comment: There isn't any violence in the original idiom. Actually, what the metaphor seems to imply is that only dirt can get in between the flesh and the nail. So when one is interfering between two people having an argument s/he is being like 'dirt'..

Answer (score 1):

> Don't poke your nose where it's not wanted

This phrase means roughly the same as yours, without the painful metaphor!

It is an appeal to [nosy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nosy) people to not meddle in others' affairs.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really convey the meaning expressed in the saying I provided -- to poke your nose between TWO people --just two.

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible suggestions:

1. **Mind your own business!**
2. ***Come not between the Nazgûl and his prey! Or he will not slay thee in thy turn. He will bear thee away to the houses of lamentation, beyond all darkness, where thy flesh shall be devoured, and thy shrivelled mind be left naked to the Lidless Eye.***

If the first one doesn’t work, then try the second: I promise it will get their attention. :)

Comment: So if we use this in a situation like someone trying unsuccessfully to mediate in a conjugal dispute, which spouse would you suppose would be the Nazgûl, and which the prey?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This is one of those scenarios where the speaker refers to themself in the third person. Should the speaker be feminine, merely switch both instances of *he* to *she*.

Answer (score 1):

***[Like yanking on a dog's ears.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=proverbs%2026%3A17&version=TLB)***

For several hundred years, the full proverb has been translated into English, but I like Kenneth Taylor's rendition:

> Interfering in someone else’s argument is as foolish as yanking a dog’s ears
>
> Proverbs 26:17

Answer (score 0):

**"Silence is Golden"**      Not specific for "don't meddle into a heated argument", it can still be used in the situation you have mentioned.  It is used in circumstances where saying nothing is preferable to speaking.

> from [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/silence-is-golden) - "said to mean **it is often better to say nothing**"

Answer (score 0):

**[stick your snoot in/into (sth)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/stick-your-snoot-in-into-sth?topic=curiosity)**:

Collins dictionary states-

- to try to discover things or influence events that are not really
  your affair:
- ***Stop sticking your snoot into other people's business***!

Answer (score -1):

@ermanen's answer may be the idiomatic equivalent of your literal translation but I believe that in the context (as supplied by your comment below) the saying should be interpreted as:
*Don't do the work of the devil*.

We'd call that *playing devil's advocate* (usually preceded by *'please stop'*). That answer also connotes more of a warning that you shouldn't get involved for  some reason, rather than saying that you shouldn't intentionally cause mischief.

**devil's advocate**; noun -[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/devil%27s+advocate)

> 1. a person who advocates an opposing or unpopular view, often for the sake of argument

---

Old answer:

*Don't sully yourself*; Usually: *with (something)*. This cliche appears in 15k [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=dont%20sully%20yourself&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22don%27t%20sully%20yourself%22&start=0) hits.

Sully:  -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sully)

> to make soiled or tarnished
>
> Middle English *sullien*, probably alteration (influenced by Anglo-French *suillier, soiller* to soil) of *sulen* **to soil**

Comment: -You seemed kinda hung-up on the whole 'dirt' thing; I thought this of note.

Comment: The saying, in fact, has a religious connotation. In Muslim culture dirt represents Satan (Shaytan) who is always depicted as an instigator who likes to see people unhappy, argue, fight, split or kill each other -- hence the metaphor.

Comment: Sounds like the idiom *Playing* [*Devil's Advocate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate).

Comment: The devil is not mentioned in the saying -- it's implied; and to be honest,  this is the first time I thought about the true meaning of the idiom. I maintain, ermanen's answer is the closed to the intended meaning in my saying -- don't interfere when TWO people are arguing.